# Stop AppleUSBMultitouchDriver From Trying

Tags: keyboard, driver, multi-touch

I am having problems with the multitouch subsystem of my MacBook Pro. But I am happy working with an external USB keyboard. But: that multitouch driver keeps trying to load, I think. Sometimes it affects my external mouse and keyboard performance. So, therefore, I'd like the AppleUSBMultitouchDriver to stop trying.

I get these messages in Console, about once a second:

```
Sep 17 17:57:24 jmbp kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_getFeatureReportInfo - DeviceRequest returned error 0xe00002c0 (interface 1, reportID 0xa1)
Sep 17 17:57:24 jmbp kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDebug: _getFeatureReportInfo returned an error in AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_deviceGetReportWithLookUp
Sep 17 17:57:24 jmbp kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_getFeatureReportInfo - DeviceRequest returned with result 0xe00002c0 - retrying (reportID 0xd9)
Sep 17 17:57:24 jmbp kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_getFeatureReportInfo - DeviceRequest returned error 0xe00002c0 (interface 1, reportID 0xd9)
Sep 17 17:57:24 jmbp kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDebug: _getFeatureReportInfo returned an error in AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_deviceGetReportWithLookUp
```

Going to sleep sometimes helps, but sometimes not. And this driver problem even affects how easy it is to go to sleep, the depth of sleep. So an effective method to just keep this loop from happening would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an older OS X, but try with:

```
sudo kextunload -b  com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch
```

Comment: Tried it and had partial success, I think. Got "Failed to unload com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch - (libkern/kext) kext is in use or retained (cannot unload)." but console logging changed a bit, I think it got reduced, and it may have helped system responsiveness a bit. Will try it again next time the problem appears...